# NGINX 504 Gateway Time-out changing system date

Tags: django, date, nginx, timeout

I'm working in a django application with a nginx proxy. In my app, I need to be able to change system date, but nginx always throws a 504 Gateway Time-out because it does not restart the init session time.

Anyone can say me how to disable nginx connection timeouts?

This is my nginx config file:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    #Added by Denis
    fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 31536000;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 31536000;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 31536000;

    max_execution_time 31536000;

    proxy_connect_timeout 31536000;
    proxy_send_timeout 31536000;
    proxy_read_timeout 31536000;

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 31536000;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

   # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/java$

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Comment: have you tried **sudo killall -9 uwsgi** ?

Comment: before reload the template? @cjahangir

Comment: I lose the server connection if I do a "killall" or "service uwsgi stop". I need to be able to continue the http session without visible interrupts for the user.